# NHibernate mapping creating duplicate foreign keys

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 POCOs mapped as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="APPayment" table="APPayments">
        <id name="PaymentId">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="Invoice" class="APInvoice" cascade="none" 
            column="InvoiceId" index="ixPaymentInvoice" not-null="true" />
    </class>
    <class name="APInvoice" table="APInvoices">
        <id name="InvoiceId">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
        <bag name="Payments" inverse="true" cascade="none" >
            <key column="PaymentId" foreign-key="fkInvoicePayments" />
            <one-to-many class="APPayment" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

For some reason I cannot fathom, I am generating duplicate foreign keys on my `APPayments` table:

```
fk9cdfbf509640182e
fkinvoicepayments
```

I think this is causing some other problems with saving the object relationships as well.  Did I misconfigure a mapping?  What do I need to do to get this working properly?

Comment: I can't find an error in the mapping, I had many problems like this when working a couple of years ago with NHibernate but using Fluent NHibernate for the mappings helped me a lot. In strict theory writing mappings with Fluent NHibernate should be exatly the same as writting an XML mapping but the fluent dsl hides many hard configurations as foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
<key column="PaymentId" ...
```

The `key` to the collection should be the **InvoiceId**.

Comment: I have tried both.  Not explicitly naming the fk makes 2 fx with those long hex names; explicitly naming the fk on both sides generates an error that the fk already exists.